# Join en SQL Con diferentes tablas

Tags: sql

Tengo 3 tablas:

Estados, Municipios y Localidades, cada una con su Id, y deseo relacionarlas para obtener a que estado y municipio pertenecen las localidades, pero el detalle es que tengo los datos de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al generar el join me une cada id estado con cada idLocalidad, y yo deseo solo obtener las correspondientes, espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: puedes mostrarnos el query que estás utlizando?

Comment: Por favor pon todas las tablas que tienes con su estructura, algún dato de ejemplo y el resultado que quieres obtener. También agrega la etiqueta con el motor de base de datos y versión que estás usando

Comment: No sé qué tabla es la que presentas en la imagen. En un modelo relacional tendrías las tablas siguientes: `pais`,  `estado`, `municipio` y `localidad`. La relacion de las mismas sería: `localidad` relacionada con `municipio`, la cual a su vez se relacionaría con `estado` la cual a su vez se relacionaría con `pais`. O sea: `pais <- estado <- municipio <- localidad`.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por su ayuda!! Lamentablemente no puedo modificar la estructura de esas tablas =( pero logré resolverlo mediante un store procedure que me almacenara en una tabla temporal los datos dado el estado del que se quiere obtener, luego realizo el join a la tabla Localidades y listo!

Comment: Recuerda que puedes contestar tus propias preguntas, puedes revisar [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Sería bueno que agregues tu respuesta e indiques como lo solucionaste.

Comment: **_Lamentablemente no puedo modificar la estructura de esas tablas_** Esa información debió constar cuando planteaste la pregunta. Son detalles importantes de saber para dar respuestas más adecuadas a la realidad. No obstante, si algún día tienes que diseñar tú las tablas de la BD al menos ya sabes que hay otras posibilidades.

Answer (score 5):

Yo diseñaría mis tablas así:

```
estado    : estado_id, estado, pais_id
municipio : municipio_id, municipio, estado_id
localidad : localidad_id, localidad, municipio_id
```

**Índices únicos:**

- En la tabla `estado` serían las columnas: `estado` y `pais_id` (ya que dos estados se podrían llamar igual pero pertenecer a países distintos).
- En la tabla `municipio` serían las columnas: `municipio` y `estado_id` (ya que dos municipios se pueden llamar igual pero pertenecer a estados distintos)
- En la tabla `localidad` serían las columnas: `localidad` y `municipio_id` (ya que  dos localidades se pueden llamar igual pero pertenecer a municipios distintos)

Conocerías el estado al que pertenece una localidad usando el municipio al que pertenece.

Ejemplo de consulta:

```
SELECT e.estado, m.municipio, l.localidad
FROM localidad l
INNER JOIN municipio m ON l.municipio_id = m.municipio_id
INNER JOIN estado e    ON m.estado_id = e.estado_id
```

La columna `estado_id` no hace falta en la tabla `localidad`... puedes llegar al estado por su municipio. Y aunque hayas *heredado* un diseño en el cual se incluye la columna `estado_id` en la tabla `localidad`, puedes ignorar dicha columna pensando en una futura optimización, siempre y cuando las relaciones entre `municipio` y `estado` sean correctas.

Si hicieran falta los países, se aplicaría el mismo criterio, la única que haría referencia al país aparte de su tabla propia, sería la tabla `estado`.